# Achievements view - "Close" instead of "Cancel"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ios-app

Currently in the Achievements view there is a "Cancel" button to dismiss the view. Shouldn't it say "Close"?

P.S.,
Sorry for the large image, there is no resize option when using the iOS app...

[image]

Comment: Oh I do like that feature request. Looks good.

Comment: @mhlester We're going to end up implementing it as is in the beta build, rather than a split view side bar., so this feature request will be relevant. I or Arie will give more details on why we chose this view when we end up shipping it.

Comment: The latest version says `Done` instead of `Cancel`. Inbox also opens the same way, so there's consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest build shows "Done", so all should be well.